# Adding user input to an arraylist without nextLine

Tags: java, input, arraylist

I am trying to add user input into an arraylist until someone types "quit". The problem is the .nextLine() method on scanner. It will skip a line so the final ArrayList will only have every other input.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Question {

static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
static List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Please enter your strings:");

    while(!userInput.nextLine().equals("quit")) {

        String v = userInput.nextLine();
        strings.add(v);


        }

    displayList();


}

private static void displayList() {
    System.out.println(strings);

}


}
```

I have tried using userInput.toString() instead of nextLine() but it is still not working. Is there a way to make it so **every** user input is added to the ArrayList?

Eg. If I enter one two three four quit, the displayed list will be [two, four].

(Another annoying thing that happens is if I type an odd number of strings, I need to type "quit" twice for it to actually quit.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question {

    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    static List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your strings:");
        String v;
        while (true){
            v = userInput.next();
            if(v.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
                break;
            else
                strings.add(v);
        }
        displayList();
    }
    private static void displayList() {
        System.out.println(strings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 'v' in your while loop instead of calling nextLine. So you would have

```
String v;
do{
 v = userInput.nextLine();
 if(v.equals("quit"))
   break;
 else
   strings.add(v);
} while(true);
```

*or*

```
String v = userInput.nextLine();
while(!v.equals("quit"))
{
 strings.add(v);
 v = userInput.nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling userInput.nextLine() twice, once in the while's header and once in the while's body. You need to use:

```
String line = "";
while(!line.equals("quit")) {
    line = userInput.nextLine();
    strings.add(line);
}
```